# How do you change the primary key, when rows have the same value?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I added a new row to my Payable table named id (int 5) and want to change the primary key from stock (int 5) to id. However when I created the id row sql inserted a 0 value for each row. How do I alter the table, giving each row an auto incremented value starting at 10001 and make that the primary key?

Comment: With AUTO_INCREMENT, of course. That's exactly what it's for.

Comment: Thanks for not reading the entire question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this (since MySQL allows in-line assignments):

```
SET @var = 10000;
UPDATE Payable
SET id = (@var := @var + 1);
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e7a361/1)

Comment: MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). (Query took 0.0005 seconds.) 

 0 rows affected. (Query took 0.0109 seconds.)

Comment: Did you run both statements together? I will test myself when I'm home tonight and let you know.

Comment: Fixed.  I added a Demo link.  Try for yourself.